# dockerfile to connect to external database

Tags: php, oracle, docker

I am deploying a php website on apache webserver. This needs to connect to an external oracle database running on a host onpremise. How can this be achieved inside a dockerfile?
My dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.3-apache
COPY . /app
COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /app && a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: are u sure you should connect it in your docker file ? i think you should try it in your manifest file

Comment: No I mean I am not sure how this should be done in a better way. Do you mean it does not need any cofiguration in dockerfile ?

Comment: i think if your database is external service and it's working now you need to connect it to your app with the manifest

Comment: See Oracle's docker files https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/main/OracleLinuxDevelopers/oraclelinux7/php/  Also look at the Instant Client docker examples (and links etc) in https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1

Comment: If database you are trying to connect is some external service and not docker container running along side your docker image with php website then you don't need any extra configuration. Just configure your php application to connect to it, build docker container and run it.

Comment: PS: I'ts not good idea to bake into final docker image that will be then shipped (deployed to production server) credentials to your database (and other sensitive data). Instead provide them ideally via ENV variables or if you have some configuration file (eg. `db-config.php`) for your app you can mount it via `docker -v "path-on-host/db-config.php:path-in-container/db-config.php"`